# Can I free memory allocated for parameters when SHChangeNotify is called with the SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT parameter?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, shell32

I have the following declaration for SHChangeNotify :

```
[DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
public static extern void SHChangeNotify(HChangeNotifyEventID wEventId, HChangeNotifyFlags uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);
```

Is the following code safe ?

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(@"C:\foo\bar.txt");
Shell.SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH | SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, ptr, IntPtr.Zero);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

[The doc on SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that "The function should begin delivering notifications to all affected components but should return as soon as the notification process has begun".

When I'm calling FreeHGlobal on ptr should I be worried of releasing memory that could still be used somewhere or does SHChangeNotify work on a copy of the string ?

My tests show that my code is working, but I don't want to deploy that and see problems arise later...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SHChangeNotify` takes a copy of your string. You can safely, and indeed should, free the memory as soon as the call to `SHChangeNotify` returns.

Comment: If you think about it, that's the only possibly way it could work. (Otherwise, how would you know when it was safe to free the memory?)